# When I need to say "I develop software" in Japanese which verb is the appropriate one?

Tags: translation, verbs

I want to say "I develop software" in Japanese so I thought that I should use the verb する. But I can also say "I write software" and use the verb かく. So which of the following sentences is the correct one/used the most?

> ソフトエアをかく。==> I write software.
>
> ソフトエアをする。==> I do (develop) software.

Similarly I thought that I can use the word source code/code in order to say "I code"/"I am coding":

> ソズコードをかく。
>
> ソズコードをする。

Which one of the above is the correct one?

Comment: Have you consulted any good dictionaries? https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=software+developer & https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/software+developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, the more/most common way to say this is either

> - ソフト(ウエア)を開発しています　→　(lit.) I develop software
>     or
> - ソフト開発をしています　→　I "do" software development

(notice the different placement of 開発).

Also, remember that you don't necessarily need a verb to get your point across.  Depending on the context, you could simply say

> - (私は)ソフト開発者です　→　I'm a software developer

Then if your listener/audience doesn't know what all that entails, you can expound on it with specifics ("I write source code", "I create user documentation", etc.)