# How to say "Developer" In Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, kanji, nuances, katakana, business-japanese

I want to know how to say Developer in Japanese. By Developer, Specifically a web Developer, Programmer or Coder.

When I googled it initially, I got:

> デベロッパー

And then I found a Kanji:

> 開発者

I know context is also very important in Japanese so I was wondering if the above are correct for developer and which would be better to use for this occasion.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65177/when-i-need-to-say-i-develop-software-in-japanese-which-verb-is-the-appropriat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are perfectly correct, and the difference is small. But, as you said, context is very important, and we need much more context to say which is better. In what kind of context do you want to say "(web) developer"? In general, 開発者 is a relatively stiffer and more traditional word, and it may be preferred in news articles and official government documents. On the other hand, デベロッパー may sound a little more "catchy", and it may be preferred in event names, product names and such. (エンジニア is another word which is gaining more and more popularity, and you may want to consider this if you are thinking of recruiting a good frontend engineer, for example.)

Comment: I want to use it in the content of my online portfolio. I want to say "Web Developer" as my job title.

Comment: @Mark Then my first recommendation is Webエンジニア (or more specific フロントエンドエンジニア, etc). But Webデベロッパ and Web開発者 are not wrong at all. Also check [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15807/5010).